# Remove carousel arrows if the image is not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to remove the arrows from the carousel when there is no image present. The reason for me trying to do so, is simply because I am trying to load several images into a carousel from a database into a given section. This section is recreated multiple times and it doesn't always contain images.

The issue that I am having is that, whenever the **bootstrap carousel** doesn't have any images loaded, it just displays the **carousel arrows** on the side. This gives a bad look to the current section and I would like to dispose of that.

> How can I remove the carousel arrows when there aren't any images
>   loaded in the carousel?

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30662/) which contains what I've done so far, it is heavy inspired by several other posts. This only removes the left arrow on the **first slide** and the right arrow on the **last slide**.

Here you can preview how does the carousel look whenever there are absent images. I have set a **black background** of **400px** in order for the arrows to be more easily spotted. [Absent Images JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30663/)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="main_area">
                <!-- Slider -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12" id="slider">
                        <!-- Top part of the slider -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8" id="carousel-bounding-box">
                                <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                                    <!-- Carousel items -->
                                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=one"></div>

                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=two"></div>

                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=three"></div>

                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=four"></div>

                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=five"></div>

                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=six"></div>
                                    </div><!-- Carousel nav -->
                                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>                                       
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next" id="arrow-right">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>                                       
                                    </a>                                
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/Slider-->
        </div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false,
})

$(document).ready(function () {               // on document ready
    checkitem();
});

            $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', checkitem);

            function checkitem()                        // check function
            {
          var $this = $('#myCarousel');
          if ($('.carousel-inner .item:first').hasClass('active')) {
              $this.children('.left.carousel-control').hide();
          } else if ($('.carousel-inner .item:last').hasClass('active')) {
              $this.children('.right.carousel-control').hide();
          } else {
              $this.children('.carousel-control').show();

          }
            }

      $("img").error(function(){
        $(this).hide('#arrow-right');
            });
});
```

Here are the answers that I've already checked for solutions:
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467666/bootstrap-carousel-hide-controls-on-first-and-last)[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728140/remove-bootstraps-carousel-item-if-image-not-found)

**Thank you in advance**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you could try something like..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($('.carousel-inner .item img').attr('src') == '') { 
      $('.carousel-control').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabqffcw/)